# How to configure webpack to load glyphicons/font-awesome icons in React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

When use bootstrap in react project, run dev environment work fine. but when I run npm build for package project. show bootstrap font error.

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
Module parse failed: /Users/xx/WorkDir/react-leap/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/xx/WorkDir/react-leap/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.getTokenFromCode (/Users/xx/WorkDir/react-leap/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2831:8)
```

**My Webpack config**

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      include: paths
    }
  ]
}
```

Bootstrap version:

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.6",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come across a solutions to this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module: {
    preLoaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'jshint-loader'}
    ],
    loaders: [
        {test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
        {test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'},
        {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
        {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
        {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
        {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
        {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
    ]
}
```

Make sure to install all these loaders

```
npm i jshint-loader style-loader css-loader less-loader url file --save-dev
```

After this import bootstrap in you file as

```
require('bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less');
```

Comment: in my case #iefix in fowtawesome.css file prevented a match with test regular expression, you have to either remove these from fotawesome.css or edit your test regex to include them